# How can I change accepting responses option in googleapis npm to a form?

Tags: node.js, npm, google-api, google-forms-api

I would like to open and close form with a node web application like this code (setAcceptingResponses), I am using googleapis npm and I don´t know how I can do something similar because in doc nothing appears about that in nodejs. If someone knows the request or the solution I would appreciate to know it.
[image: Doc image]

I have tried to batchUpdate the form but I can´t find the request needed

Answer (score 0):

As of now, checking available resources using Google Forms API, there isn't any feature yet available to directly open / close a Google Form. You can submit a [feature request](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/new?component=978479&template=1644354) here instead.

**SUGGESTION:**

If not, a workaround that is currently possible is using Google Apps Script API instead to run an Apps Script function using Node.js. You can check this [reference article](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/quickstart/nodejs) or a quickstart guide on how to setup Apps Script API.

So the concept would be, using the code you presented as a sample above can be initiated using the Apps Script API.

Reference: https://developers.google.com/apps-script/api/concepts

Comment: If I misunderstood your question and this was not the result you want, I apologize. Feel free to clarify below if this was not the result you want.

If this answers your question, please click the accept button on the left (check icon) and upvoting the answer.  By doing so, other people in the community, who may have the same concern as you, will know that theirs can be resolved.  If the accept button is unavailable to you, feel free to tell me. [how to accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)